# Prevent folder creation at top-level only?

Tags: folder, online, subfolders

We are running SharePoint online and I've got a question.

So we all know about the: Library Settings > Make "New Folder" command available toggle

Well, this propagates across the entire document library and all sub folders.

**Is there anyway to only make this command apply to the top level of the library and not sub folders?** - or is this only really possible with SharePoint server?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you do this in SharePoint Server?

Comment: Are you using classic experience or modern. I think in the classic you can create custom folder content type and show it only in root. but that doesn't work for modern that feature seems to be broken (or at least was few months ago when I have tested it)

Comment: Derek I don't even know for sure if it is possible on SPS, I just know SPS is much more customizable then SPO